# Blackberry In App purchase using valid credit card returning Failure reason "-224718155"

Tags: blackberry, in-app-purchase

I am trying to purchase some in-app goods with a valid credit card, using a sandbox account while the application is in draft mode on appworld.  It is sending me PurchaseResult Object  containing failure reason as -224718155. Why is it failing while I am using a valid Credit card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the code for a successful purchase by the user:)

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/payment/1.8api/constant-values.html